# Quiero crear una expresión regular para validar un campo de calificaciones

Tags: regex, validación

La idea es poder validar a través de una expresión regular el campo para calificaciones (Notas de colegio). De esta manera:

> La nota mínima sea: 0.0
> La nota máxima sea: 5.0

Estuve tratando con esta expresión pero, me permite 5.9:

```
^[0-5]+([.][0-9]+)?$/
```

Me podrían ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^([0-4]{1}([.][0-9]{1,2})?|5(\.0)?)$/gm
```

Esta sería la expresion que buscas simplemente no debes dejar que se pueda poner mas de 5.0 restringiendo el primer corchete [0-4], y luego con un OR contemplar que se pueda el 5.0
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos @PabloRodriguez, el código siempre debe ir en formato de texto, solo utiliza imágenes cuando sea absolutamente necesario, por favor lee [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), también te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así obtener tu primera medalla. ;)

Comment: Hola Pablo, muchas gracias. Excelente. Ya la probé y está perecta !!

Comment: @Israel-ICM Entonces para obtener la medalla que tengo que borrar la imagen y poner el codigo en formato texto?

Comment: @PabloRodriguez, solo leer el recorrido para informarte de como funciona la web, lo más correcto seria que modifiques tu respuesta tal como lo hiciste y si pudieras explicar por partes tu código o agregar enlaces de documentación seria genial, de esta manera tu respuesta será mejor recibida por la comunidad. ;)

Comment: @PabloRodríguez 
Muchas gracias por la ayuda y la participación. 
Estuve revisando la validación y me está permitiendo agregar mas de 2 caracteres que empiecen por 1. así: 111100 ó 10. Ya los aceptaba
Le quité el signo de interrogación y parece que está funcionando bien.
La dejé así: /^([0-4]+([.][0-9]+)|5(\.0)?)$/gm

Comment: El `?` estaba bien. Lo que está mal es el `+`. No hay que permitir que se repita el primer dígito. Reemplazá `[0-4]+` por `[0-4]`

Comment: ^([0-4]{1}([.][0-9]{1,2})?|5(\.0)?)$/gm  Es verdad, sería así.